# Setting up kerberos authentication for hive jdbc connection from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I had setup a jdbc connection to Hortonworks hive jdbc installation from Eclipse and from the Eclipse Data source explorer I was able to connect to the cluster and run queries. Recently kerberos authentication was applied on the cluster and now I am seeing the below error, could you please let me know what configurations are needed to be able to connect to hive jdbc in a kerberos environment from eclipse

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge.createClientWithConf(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:87)
    at org.apache.hive.service.auth.KerberosSaslHelper.getKerberosTransport(KerberosSaslHelper.java:54)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.createBinaryTransport(HiveConnection.java:423)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:185)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:158)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
```

Comment: AFAIK, with the clunky Apache Hive JDBC driver, you need *(a)* some URL options to state that you use Kerberos auth, *(b)* extra Hive and Hadoop JARs, *(c)* a Hadoop run-time **compiled for Windows** including `winutils.exe` and its companion DLLs -- the trick is that is there is no official build for Windows... *(d)* some Java system properties to point to that runtime, and finally *(e)* either a valid Kerberos ticket managed by **MIT Kerberos for Windows** or a JAAS config file to describe how to build that Kerberos ticket dynamically.

Comment: With the Cloudera Hive JDBC driver (based on Simba SDK) you can skip steps *(b)-(c)-(d)* -- and it ships with a detailed user manual. Plus, it has a much better support of JDBC basic features.

Comment: Also, to add to what Samson said, if you're running it on Windows, you'll also need the `krb5.conf` file along with the keytab and all that jazz. And to add, Kerberos error messages are the worst!

Comment: Thank you @SamsonScharfrichter , will check the above options

Comment: I have setup kerberos and setup all the required libraries and now I am seeing this error - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: class org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback not org.apache.hadoop.security.GroupMappingServiceProvider

Comment: @venkata, hi do you have a solution for this error when using kerberos?
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: class org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback not org.apache.hadoop.security.GroupMappingServiceProvider